# How to avoid repeating when I get data from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I get a list from stored procedure with its child date I want to avoid repeating when I add items to the the list

Here is my code:

```
var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[T]";

db.Database.Connection.Open();
var reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

var objectContext1 = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
var usersLi = objectContext1.Translate<GetAllNewsForUser>(reader1).ToList();

List<GetAllNewsForUser> lll = new List<GetAllNewsForUser>();

foreach (var item in usersLi)
{
    NewsInfo newsInfo = new NewsInfo();

    GetAllNewsForUser g = new GetAllNewsForUser();
    g.UserName = item.UserName;

    NewsInfo nnn = new NewsInfo();
    nnn.NewsTitle = item.NewsTitle;
    nnn.NewsId = item.NewsId;

    g.NewsInfos.Add(nnn);
    lll.Add(g);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are there any unique identifiers for g, for example a user Id. in which case you could easily use the following:

```
if (!lll.Any(x=>x.UserId ==g.UserId)) //include system.linq
{
    lll.Add(g);
}
```

You could also look at modifying your stored procedure to not return duplicates.

EDIT ----
Just twigged as to what you actually after, sorry.....

Its just a rough draft but i think this is what you require.

```
 List<GetAllNewsForUser> lll = new List<GetAllNewsForUser>();
 foreach (var item in usersLi)
 {
     NewsInfo nnn = new NewsInfo();
     nnn.NewsTitle = item.NewsTitle;
     nnn.NewsId = item.NewsId;

     if (!lll.Any(x=> x.UserName == item.UserName)
     { 

          GetAllNewsForUser g = new GetAllNewsForUser();
          g.UserName = item.UserName;
          g.NewsInfos.Add(nnn);
          lll.Add(g);

     }
     else
     {
          lll.Where(x=>x.UserName == item.Username).FirstOrDefault().NewsInfos.Add(nnn)

     }        


 }
```

Comment: It's working!! thank you so much Chris :) i am actually new to programming so my question is is my code can cause any conflation since i am gather it parent rows with child rows by for loop this is my question. my second question is i think it's better to avoid  repeating in stored procedure i've tried SELECT distinct  but didn't work. Again thank you so much for your effort, God bless you :)

Comment: The best practice (I believe) if you are using entity framework would be to let EF handle a lot of the loading for example ---- var q = c in context.Users.Include("NewsInfo") select c; ---- this would populate all users news info automatically.

Comment: Yes i know but i t-sql is much faster than linq .. Is there another way to avoid repeating than SELECT distinct? because SELECT distinct is not working

Comment: I would only use stored procedures for more complex operations, the speed difference is minimal especially when you have to sort your results. I am not aware of a SP call that will sort out your object relationships as you require which is why i suggested a linq select - speed shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand so far, you are trying to avoid adding same rows in the list(based on value of some column).
LINQ might help here.

```
usersLi.GroupBy(e => new { 
                      UserID = e.UserUD 
                   }).Select(g => g.First());
```